# Value of textboxfor is always comming null to controller action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm passing email id from view to controller using jquery but it is always comming null to controller.

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.receiversEmailID)
```

jQuery Code:

```
  var exportUrl = "/Export/Download?receiversEmailID=" + $("#receiversEmailID").val();
```

Question as below:

I tried to use modelbinding rather than passing it like above but model also getting null. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: What is the html output in your browser? What is the result of `alert($("#receiversEmailID").val());`? Please update your post.

Comment: it is blank...no value is comming in alert

Comment: Then you answered your question by yourself.

Comment: it is blank but ..i didn't get,why it is comming blank.I tried <input type="text" id="receiversEmailId" value="abc@xyz.com">.then this value is comming.But if I enter value from Ui then it is blank.

Comment: What is your controller.. Are you sure that `Model.receiversEmailID` is having something in it. try
`<script>
alert(Model.receiversEmailID);
</script>`

Comment: @Asha How looks the html outlook of your input field?

Comment: Maybe you use a class instead a id ?